# How does one remove wires from this wire joint / splice?

Tags: wiring, splices

Pics of the joint / splice below.

I need to remove 2 of the wires, and replace them with 2 new wires.

(This is a defrost thermostat sensor for a refrigerator. The part number that needs to be replaced is `37Tv31`. The part is easily bought off the internet.)

Can I just pull the wires out (I tugged but nothing happened) or is it more involved?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think most of them use a spring like clip to lock in.  The secret is to find something small and stiff enough to push in the right way and push the clip down.  It should only take a day or two with plenty of unfriendly language.  A pair of wire cutters and wire splices might be faster.

Comment: That's not a splice like a Wago.  That's a 2-pin Molex connector.   They're just overloading its use as a connector by also joining 2 wires on each terminal.  It still needs to plug into something.

Comment: If you are replacing the bad sensor with the proper part, why do you need to change the plug?

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri Good point. What's odd is that this plug doesn't seem to plug into anything. Or maybe it does and it popped out. Will investigate.

Answer (score 7):

Thats a Molex connector or knock-off.

The contacts are held in by little bits that spring out - if you just yank you'll ruin the contact, the housing or both.

The official tool is basically a semi-circular (or circular) bit of tubing, thin-wall, just bigger than the connector. But it can be released with any thin, stiff, strip of metal and some care.

I don't know that I've ever had the "proper tool" but I've certainly changed a few. If getting a proper tool you'll need to know the size of your contacts.

At that point you'll have a contact with wires crimped to it. You either crimp on a new contact (of the correct size and gender), or you splice your new wire to an old wire that's going away with the bad part, or you would be trying to loosen the crimp and reuse it, which may not be reliable. If you're going to end up splicing wires anyway, no need to actually remove the contact from the connector.

Comment: Well that answer made me hope I have this problem one day so that I have an excuse to buy [this](https://www.amazon.com/MENKEY-Terminal-Removal-Connector-Extractor/dp/B07ZC1V2W6/ref=sr_1_1_sspa)   I actually have an RS232 pin puller in my desk as a reminder of ye olde days.

Comment: You could always be prepared in case such a problem presented itself, if you really want the toys.

Comment: @jay613  Too bad to find out about these neat tools after spending time to make sure mother/SO/children are not in hearing range.

Comment: You may be able to use a tiny jewelers screwdriver (or a long straight pin) pushed into the business end to depress the tiny metal flap(s) on the contact that keeps it from being pulled out.  Here's a pic that shows what they look like outside the plastic housing: https://www.mobilehomerepair.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/02-08-1002.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I would cut the wires close to the bad sensor and splice the new sensor onto the remaining old sensor wires, much easier then trying to reuse a 1 use connector. Cutting close to the sensor does not damage the connector so later a new sensor could be plugged in.

Comment: Never take OP at their word. That's not a splice. That's a Molex plug. It's to plug into something.  If you replace it with a splice, you'll no longer be able to plug into that thing.